# scope bar changes to black in search mode, iOS 7

Tags: ios7, uisearchbar

when I change the background of UISearchBar in iOS 7 via interface builder or even in code, and enter in search mode, scopeBar wont be visible and instead its frame will be black? 
why that happens?
could someone explains or provide a solution?

here is a shot:

[image]

I searched but couldn't find any solution

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I did was using an image which was wide enough to fill seacrh bar background and scopeBar background. 
thats all.
first you need to create a subclass of UISearchBar and use this class as your seachBar custom class.
then in `- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` add this call

```
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"searchBarBg"]]];
```